# 'item' object has no attribute 'date' Google Cloud NDB

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am building an google appengine app using python 3.9. I use cloud ndb as a database for my app. My app has an item ndb model like this:

```
class item(ndb.Model):
  nameFr = ndb.StringProperty()
  nameAr = ndb.StringProperty()
  nameEn = ndb.StringProperty()
  price = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  customerBonus = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  employeeBounty = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  thumbnail = ndb.StringProperty()
  category = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='category')
  store = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='store')
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I successfully manage to create an instance on the cloud ndb (See the picture below)
[image: See the picture below]

However, when I try to access some attributes (The below code)

```
def item_detail(request,item_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        existingItem = item.get_by_id(int(item_id))
        itemStore = store.get_by_id(existingItem.store.id())
        itemCategory =category.get_by_id(existingItem.category.id())
        context = {'item':existingItem,
                   'store':itemStore, 
                   'category':itemCategory}
        # return render(request,'item/detail-item.html',context)
        return HttpResponse(existingItem.date)
```

I got the error. (**Only the price attribute is accessible!**)

```
AttributeError at /item/detail/6236280943804416
'item' object has no attribute 'date'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/item/detail/6236280943804416
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'item' object has no attribute 'date'
Exception Location: /Users/hizan/Desktop/mysite/item/views.py, line 79, in item_detail
Raised during:  item.views.item_detail
```

Here is the local variable when it throws the error:

```
Local vars
Variable    Value
existingItem    
item(key=Key('item', 6236280943804416), price=80)
item_id 
'6236280943804416'
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/item/detail/6236280943804416'>
```

Comment: Include your code showing you how derive/determine ```existingItem```

Comment: I have updated my post to let you see how I determine ''existingItem''

Comment: If you look at your screenshot (showing the item on cloud console), you'll see that the Id in the screenshot is different from the Id you use in your query. Run your code for item id = ```6257988832591872``` It's possible you have another item in your Datastore which only has price specified (maybe you hadn't added the other properties of the Model). It's also possible you're running your queries against datastore emulator (and hence a different item id)

Comment: I didn't notice that the id in the cloud console is different from the id in request. However my Datastore has not another model named 'item'. Also I am not running my queries against the emulator. And when I renamed my model to 'article' everything worked as it should with the same code. I find this somehow weird. Perhaps the google cloud ndb is not as reliable as other kinds of database. I am telling this because it is not the first I stumble upon this error.

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with Google Cloud Datastore. Rather I suspect it's any of the following - your code, setup, environment, stuff you tried to fix your error. Renaming should't 'solve' the issue unless there's another similarly named artifact (e.g. another model called 'item') with different properties (maybe there was a django model with it). Also, conventionally, class names should use CapWords convention - [doc](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) and so you'd have ```Article, Item```. This also helps in avoiding clashes with reserved words

Comment: I totally agree with you ''renaming a model shouldn't change anything''. I will reach you if I find new elements.

Answer (score -1):

`date` is a very common name. There may be something shading it. Can you try it again, but with `date` defined as `item_date` or something more descriptive?